# jquery document height and window height

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with following jquery code

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).innerHeight() - $(window).innerHeight()))
```

In Google chrome the code is working perfectly but in Firefox or IE it doesn't.
There's any way to rewrite it ?

Thank you!

EDIT:

After some debug.. the value of document height - window height is bigger than "window.scrollTop" so the following code is a possible fix

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).innerHeight() - $(window).height() - 2)) {
```

Comment: What happens on the other browsers? What other code are you running? This is a message board to help each other not a support line :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The end of the browser to load more results. 2 seconds to edit the first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `innerHeight()` instead of `height()`

There are some issues with `height()` and `IE`

I faced the same problem and I used `innerHeight()` and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I tried to zoom out and it works.. but when I have 100% it doesn't. This thing is really weird

Comment: use innerHeight for document and height for window.